# VGA output not working for Intel GS45 Express chipset

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, external-monitor, vga

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on my Toshiba Portege R600-10Q laptop (a model from 2009). I am now trying to display the desktop on a BenQ Senseye3 22" monitor, via the vga output, but it's not working - the monitor says "No Signal Detected!".

What I've done:

- I have gone into "Screen Display", where I can see the monitor is
  detected by the laptop.
- The monitor has a 1920 x 1080 native
  resolution, which I have tried to use, but I have also set it to
  lower resolutions, e.g. 1024 x 576.
- I have tried to use the monitor in dual screen, mirrored and single screen mode - none work.
- I have tried pressing Fn + F5 to get single screen output - the laptop
  screen goes blank, but still no output on the monitor.
- I have tried several monitors (of the same type, and also of a different make), so I don't think it's that.

If, and only if, the monitor was plugged in to the PC's vga output during boot up, then the display outputs to the monitor correctly. But if I plug the vga cable in after boot up, then the monitor receives no signal.

The laptop has the Intel® GS45 Express chipset for graphics acceleration. I installed mesa-utils and ran glxinfo in a terminal. Amongst the output was:

> OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset

Also, in the "About This Computer" window I see:

> Graphics: Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset

I wonder if the problem is that my chipset is GS45 not GM45.

Results of `sudo lshw -C video` :

```
*-display:0
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: 07
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
    resources: irq:44 memory:ff400000-ff7fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:cff8(size=8)

*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
    description: Display controller
    product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2.1
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
    version: 07
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:ffc00000-ffcfffff
```

This issue seems identical to the one in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121228/laptop-with-intel-graphics-external-vga-monitor-only-gets-signal-on-boot-no-h), which was bizarrely closed. The output above is certainly very similar. Also it seems identical to the bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1218224).

I have also filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1364292) about this.